# My sequence plsql_profile_runnumber is not visible in dba_objects

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I have created a sequence `plsql_profile_runnumber` in sys user, but I cannot find it in `dba_objects` or `dba_sequences`. Please find the executiion details:

```
SQL> create sequence plsql_profiler_runnumber start with 1 nocache;

Sequence created.

SQL> select * from sys.dba_objects where object_name ='PLSQL_PROFILE_RUNNUMBER';

no rows selected

SQL> grant select on plsql_profile_runnumber to vps_user;
grant select on plsql_profile_runnumber to vps_user
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create sequence plsql_profiler_runnumber start with 1 nocache;

select * from sys.dba_objects where object_name ='PLSQL_PROFILE_RUNNUMBER';
```

Answer: The sequence you created was PLSQL_PROFILER_RUNNUMBER.
The object name you reference was PLSQL_PROFILE_RUNNUMBER.

The two names are different. PROFILER vs. PROFILE.

Comment: Thanks ! I apologise for asking such a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

> PLSQL_PROFILE_RUNNUMBER

and

> plsql_profile`r`_runnumber

are different by 
 ending `r` of `profiler`.

Comment: Thanks ! I apologise for asking such a silly question.

Comment: @SumanPanigrahi oh no! learning accomplished by questioning ... Welcome...